# Failed to set MokListRT: Invalid Parameter - nothing loads

Tags: boot, startup, macbook, moklistrt

I know there might be similar questions, but I'm new to Linux and would need some more detailed explanations if possible please.

So I have a Macbook Pro early 2008. I removed HDD and put SSD on it installed latest Ubuntu LTS 20.04.1. System installs fine with no problems. After first restart I see message on the screen

**Failed to set MokListRT: Invalid Parameter
Could not create MokListRT: Invalid Parameter
Importing MOK states has failed: import_mok_state () failed
:Invalid Parameter
Continuing boot since secure mode is disabled**

I cant proceed anywhere after that. Laptop works but nothing is on the screen and nothing loads. I seen some posts advising to change shimx to GRUB but not sure where to start if nothing loads.

Any advice will be much appreciated!

Comment: I believe this is the [problem](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1867092) ...read its comments for potential fix

Comment: @tonyb thanks mate. But thats again shmix to grub. But in my case I dont have oiptions to change it as this error is first and only thing I see after machine starts. So not really a fix for me.

Comment: I managed to fix it. I think issue is with Nvidia drivers. I installed system again but this time with no internet access and skipped option install option for 3rd party drivers.